# Why is '0' + 1 or '1' + 1 result in a different number?

Tags: java

I'm studying for an exam and was wondering why the follow ' number ' code statements result in a number that completely different.

```
public class HelloWorld{    
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println('1' + 1); // prints 50
        System.out.println('2' + 1); // prints 51
        System.out.println('2'); // prints 2
     }
}
```

Comment: `char` vs `int` representations. also `System.out.println('2' + 1);` prints `51`.

Comment: `'1'` is not the same as `1` and it would be surprising that they would be the same given they have two different representations.

Comment: I suggest you look at the ASCII table here http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Just to be thoroughly pedantic, '1' and '2' are Unicode characters in Java, not ASCII, it's just that the Unicode code point and the Latin-1 or ASCII values all happen to be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say `'1'` and you add `1`, the values are promoted to `int` before adding ([binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)).  [`1` has the ASCII value `49`](http://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php), so 49 + 1 = 50, and `2` has the ASCII value `50`, so 50 + 1 = 51.

However, if you don't add, then the [`println` method that takes a `char`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28char%29) is called, and `'2'` is printed.

Comment: +1 for binary numeric promotion.. never heard that term before but always understood it

Answer (score 2):

http://www.asciitable.com/

The ASCII value for 1 is 49, so when doing `System.out.println('1' + 1);`, the char `'1'` is first converted to its ASCII value (49) and then 1 is added, resulting in 50.

In the last example, there is no addition, so the character is not converted to its integer representation.

Likewise, you could add `'f'` and `1`:

```
System.out.println('f' + 1); // prints: 103
```

Answer (score 0):

**System.out.println('1' + 1);**

Java will see an arithmetic operation and try to print the result of that operation.  Therefore, Java will convert the char `'1'` into the ASCII code value which is 49.  49 + 1 = 50 so it prints "50"

**System.out.println('2');**

There is no arithmetic here so it just prints the char

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether there is arithmetic but what type is passed to `println` and thus which overload of `println` is selected by the compiler. `System.out.println((int)'2')` doesn't do any arithmetic, but will still print "50".

Answer (score 0):

First `'2'+1` equals to 51 ,not 50.

The number inside the singlequates is represents as an ascii value and its not the real number. The ascii of 1 is 49 , 49 and 1 equals 50.Check the ascii code [here](http://www.asciitable.com)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all above answers.
When you type  `System.out.println('2');`  //It just prints the string 2.

Refer http://www.newebgroup.com/academy/tables/ascii.htm for detailed ascii values.

Comment: `'2'` is not a string, it is a char.

Answer (score 0):

When you use single quotes, `'1'`, Java parses this as a `char` type. When you perform an operation on a char type with an `int`, Java will take the decimal value of that char and use it for the operation. Using an [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you can see the ascii value for `'1'` is `49` (and `'2'` is `50`), so adding `1` you get `50` and `51` respectively. `System.out.println` will then print out the `int` result.

When you use `System.out.println('2')`, it will print out the `char` ascii value, which is why you get `2`.

Answer (score 0):

`'1'` indicates a character and it [ASCII](http://www.newebgroup.com/academy/tables/ascii.htm) value is `49`.
It is added to 1 so you got `50`.

In the last case you dont add anything to `char` , so [println](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28char%29) prints `2`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println('1' + 1); // prints 50
System.out.println('2' + 1); // prints 51
System.out.println('2'); // prints 2
```

When your parameter is being parsed, it will assume the entire expression should of type `int`. Therefore, it will convert the `char` `'1'` to its ASCHII value (`int` value), which is `49`. 
Therefore `49 + 1 = 50`.

Similarly, `'2' == 50` so `50 + 1 = 51`.

However, when you pass just the `'2'` as a parameter, it will simply print the `char` as is, because it has no reason to be parsed into an `int`, like in the other cases.